# How can I switch multiple circuits using switches with limited pole counts?

Tags: switches, switching

I am trying to refine the design of an audio switch that I built a while ago. Since this is used to connect two inputs (two sound cards) to five possible outputs (speakers, tv, etc) with stereo audio plugs, I am dealing with three circuits. Since finding triple-throw, triple-pole switches is difficult, I was forced to wire the ground directly to all possible outputs (the ground isn't switched) which sometimes causes audible interference. I was therefore wondering, is there a way to control more circuits using simple switches? What if somebody needs to switch four circuits at a time? Or five?

I am a software dev and just beginning with hardware tinkering so please excuse this being so elementary.

Comment: You may consider using relays.

Comment: The electronic solution is to use a crosspoint switch (a chip), then the mechanical switches could be as simple as you like. Other than that, Bruno's suggestion is a good one. You can parallel as many relay coils as you need, if one does not have enough contacts. There are bistable relays that just need a pulse to change state and are appropriate for switching audio.

Answer (score 1):

Search for wafer switches.

They are rotary switches, which used to be available [(update : still are!)](http://uk.farnell.com/jsp/search/results.jsp?N=0&Ntk=gensearch&Ntt=wafer%20switch&Ntx=mode%20matchallpartial&suggestions=false&ref=globalsearch&_requestid=15727) as pre-built configurations, or in modular form with up to [12 ways](http://uk.farnell.com/nsf-controls/ma112n-454623-1-ma/wafer-ma-1pole-12-pos/dp/146049) on each wafer and as many wafers as you felt like stacking behind the [switch body](http://uk.farnell.com/nsf-controls/mu-454882fpa-ma/mechanism-ma-30-deg-metal/dp/1165268).

A [4-pole 3-way switch](http://uk.farnell.com/multicomp/ra01d03bsfmsox/switch-rotary-4-pole-3-pos/dp/1566718) is a single wafer, one of the simpler standard configurations.